# Prove that a set does not have Baire property

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

A set is called meager if it can be written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets. A set $S$ is said to have Baire property if there is an open set $O$ such that the symmetric difference $S\Delta O$ is meager.

> **The Set $M$**: Let us define an equivalence relation on $[0,1]$: $x\sim y$ if $x-y\in\Bbb Q$. Let $[x]$ be the equivalence class of $x$. Then by axiom of choice we have choice function $f$ for the family of sets $\mathfrak{F}=\{[x]\mid x\in[0,1]\}$. Let us define $$M=\{f([x])\mid[x]\in\mathfrak{F}\}$$ i.e., *$M$ contains exactly one element from every equivalence class defined above.*

Now I need to prove that **$M$ does not have the Baire property**.

In other words, I need to prove that there exists no open set $O$, such that $M\Delta O$ is meager.

**Is it enough to prove that there exists no open interval $(a,b)$ such that $M\Delta(a,b)$ is meager? If yes, why is it enough?**

1. Now I can easily get this property: for any $x\in\Bbb R$, there exists unique $y\in M$ and unique $r\in\Bbb Q$, such that $x=y+r$.
2. Also if for any open set $O$, if $M\Delta O$ is meager, then $(M\Delta O)^c=M^c\Delta O=M\Delta O^c$ is a countable intersection of open dense sets, which I can prove has to be dense in $\Bbb R$.

I think I can use these facts to get my end result, but is in dire need of ideas.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361296/topological-proof-that-a-vitali-set-is-not-borel